# How to remove white horizontal line in HTML tables

Tags: outlook, html-table, whitespace, html-email, horizontal-line

I think I've searched every corner of the interwebs to try and figure this problem out. I have found similar issues across the board, but none of the solutions have worked for me (either that, or I must be missing something).

I'm creating an email campaign with a table layout. In FF, Chrome and IE it all looks great, but when I test it in Outlook 2010 it gives me a horizontal white line between 2 TRs that are in the main table of the page.

Please observe 2 TRs below:
NOTE: I've edited this question to include the entire code:

```
<body>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="700" style="background-color: #ecebeb; border: solid maroon 2px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" align="center" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%"  style="background-color: #ffffff; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #000000">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="70%" cellpadding="10px" height="85">
                                        <img src="http://www.codegroup.com.au/images/Introduction%20Newsletter/CodeGroup_Logo_small.png">
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="30%" style="text-align: right" height="85">
                                        Building Certifiers<br>
                                        Building Surveyors<br>
                                        Access Auditors<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>   
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style=" padding-left: 10; padding-right: 10; padding-top: 10; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000">
                            <strong>
                            If you're designing or building, you need a Building Certifier<br>
                            CODE Group are specialist commercial Building Certifiers, Surveyors and Access Auditors.
                            </strong>
                            <hr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10; padding-right: 10; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                            We offer a comprehensive range of professional services which integrate the concept, design, approval 
                            and project completion for the property and construction industry.<br><br>
                            We understand the practical demands of the construction industry and make every effort to assist our client 
                            in finding solutions to compliance problems.<br><br>
                            Each project is approached with integrity and professional confidence to deliver the best possible solutions and 
                            premium service to our clients.<br><br>
                            We understand the urgency of your project and that it can’t move forward unless we do our part so we contact 
                            you at times during our assessment to let you know how it is progressing. <br><br>
                            <i><center>"Our mission is to manage risk for our clients in design and construction to ensure they meet
                            statutory<br>obligations whilst achieving project objectives and outcomes" </i></center>
                            <hr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%"style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25;" valign="top" >
                                        <b>BUILDING CERTIFIERS</b><br><br>
                                        Design Certification: <br>
                                        Certificate of Design Compliance<br><br>
                                        Construction Certification: <br>
                                        Certificate of Construction Compliance<br><br>
                                        Permit Coordination: <br>
                                        Building Permit & Occupancy Permit<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 25" valign="top" >
                                        <b>BUILDING CONSULTANTS</b><br><br>
                                        Preliminary Review & Report of Schematic Plans<br>
                                        Access Audits, Appraisals & Consulting<br>
                                        Due Diligence Inspections & Reports<br>
                                        Building Audits for Benchmark Compliance<br>
                                        Expert Building Code Advice<br>
                                        Fire Engineering Advice<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                            <table width="100%" style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="38%" valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 25;">
                                        <b>OUR SPECIALTIES</b><br><br>
                                        Multi Residential Towers<br>
                                        Hotel & Serviced Apartments<br>
                                        Education Buildings<br>
                                        Mixed Use Buildings <br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="38%" valign="bottom">
                                        Hospitals & Healthcare Buildings<br>
                                        Aged Care Developments<br>
                                        Shopping Centres<br>
                                        Office Buildings<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="28%" valign="bottom">
                                        Office & Retail Fitouts<br>
                                        Industrial Buildings<br>
                                        Sports Stadiums<br>
                                        Mining Projects<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10; padding-right: 10; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000" >
                            <br>
                            <b>Who we are</b><br><hr>
                            <p>CODE Group is made up of an established team of experienced members who have over 80 years building 
                            industry experience in Perth, the north-west of WA and interstate. CODE Group's teamwork is our strength.<br><br></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="53%">
                                    <img src="http://www.codegroup.com.au/images/Introduction%20Newsletter/Team-Photo_no-corners.png" align="right">                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="47%" style="padding-left: 10; padding-right: 10">
                                        <table style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                                            <tr><td>Gary Cox</td><td>Managing Director</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Wayne Chant</td><td>Co-ordinating Building Surveyor</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Paul da Costa</td><td>Senior Building Surveyor</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Tanya Scarce</td><td>Building Surveyor</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Kelly Hudson</td><td>Building Surveyor</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Alison Shiels</td><td>Access Auditor</td></tr>                          
                                            <tr><td>Antonia Yakubova&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Office Manager</td></tr>                               
                                            <tr><td>Linda Marr</td><td>Accounts Manager</td></tr>                               
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="padding-right: 10; padding-left: 10; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000">    
                            <b>Our Projects</b><hr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="middle" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="33%" style="padding-left: 20; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000" valign="top">
                                        20 Storey Mixed Use Hotel<br>
                                        Murray Street, Perth<br><br>

                                        3 Storey Mixed Use Apartments<br>
                                        215 Hay Street, Subiaco<br><br>

                                        Point Fraser Entertainment Centre<br>
                                        4500sqm, East Perth Foreshore <br><br>

                                        Observations City Refurbishment<br>
                                        Scarborough Beach
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" valign="top" style="padding-left: 20; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                                        Heritage Conversion<br>
                                        307 Murray Street, Perth<br><br>

                                        Bidvest Distribution Centre<br>
                                        107,000 cu/m Warehouse<br><br>

                                        Joondalup Square<br>
                                        13,000sqm Retail Showrooms
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" valign="top" style="padding-right: 20; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #000000">
                                        6 Storey Mixed Use Building<br>
                                        Wexford Street, Subiaco<br><br> 

                                        Fitout of Council House<br>
                                        Level 1 & Basement, Perth<br><br>

                                        Veil Offices, 4 Storey offices<br>
                                        Over existing 2 Storey Carpark<br>
                                        253 St. Georges Terrace, Perth<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="middle" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <img style="display:block;" src="http://www.codegroup.com.au/images/Introduction%20Newsletter/Introduction2_image_stack2.png">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" style="background-color: #ffffff; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 10" height="80">
                                        CODE Group<br>
                                        7 First Avenue<br>
                                        Applecross WA 6153
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%" valign="bottom" align="right" style="padding-right: 10" height="80">
                                        08 9316 8111<br>
                                        PO Box 1232<br>
                                        Canning Bridge WA 6153<br>
                                        www.codegroup.com.au
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal white line is most likely coming from the image you have in your second row.

Try setting an inline style on the `img` to have `display:block;`...

```
<img style="display:block;" src="http://www.codegroup.com.au/images/Introduction%20Newsletter/Introduction2_image_stack2.png" />
```

That typically takes care of it.

Also, I'm not sure if it was just a typo when you posted your original question, but the first `td` element in the second `tr` isn't properly closed. Your first `tr` also only has one `td`, so you may want to either eliminate the element or add a `colspan=2` to the `td` in the first row.

Comment: Unfortunately the display:block doesn't help. I also read that that doesn't work in Outlook.

Also, yes, it was a typo, there is only meant to be one TD in the second TR :) I do wish that was the solution to my problem lol.

Comment: What about adding this `style` declaration to your `table` element: `style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either, however I do like what that has done to the main table border - thanks for that one!
Anyway, I've just read somewhere that Oulook really doesn't like borders. I had a border in my main table style tag, which when I removed it, the white line was gone from between those two TR's.
So I know where the problem starts, but does that mean I cannot have a border now around the whole table?

Comment: It's possible...email templates can be a real pain. In some cases, you end up throwing good coding practices out the window. If you want a border around the whole table, what about wrapping the table in a div and applying a border to that?

Comment: That sounds great in theory.. though I seem to be experiencing a lot of difficulty with this thing. I tried the div on the very outside, nope. Tried it on the outer table, nope. Tried it on the inner main table, nope. It either throws everything out of place, or stretches across the entire page. It really is a pain.
I'll paste my entire code in...

Comment: According to http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ the border property shouldn't be a problem. You could also try applying `border-collapse:collapse` to the nested tables...and you could remove the cellspacing and cellpadding from the `td` elements. They aren't valid attributes for `td` tags.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Fletch, though unfortunately none of that worked. However, I tried moving the TD with the image into the table above it, and added colspan="3" which seems to have worked, amazingly enough!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Mailchimp template. Only on **MS Outlook** this problem with the white line showed up.

Apparently MS Outlook add's this line when the height of a table gets higher than `700px`. So for me the solution to this silly problem was to distribute the content of the email over a few tables. So it doesn't reach a height higher than `700px`.

Comment: It happens for me between tables, both of which are under 700px in height.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try in all your tables use these properties border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

something like this

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color:#4a4a4a;">
   <tr>
      <td>.....</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

probably the table is generating that white space